# Where is the best place to mine tin in WOW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to level up my mining in World of Warcraft, where should I go to find tin veins?

Comment: stop asking WoW questions. Your making the itch come back. STOP IT.

Comment: Scratch it! Scratch the itch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best places to mine Tin ore are Hillsbrad Foothills and Ashenvale along the following paths;

[image]

[image]

(images courtasy of [TheNoobSchool](http://www.thenoobschool.com/wow-tin-mining-guide))

Comment: I should also note that there's no Alliance presence in Hillsbrad anymore, so if you're an Alliance player, you may not want to go there.

Comment: this depends on whether you're on a PvP server or not, the spawns for tin ore are around a mountain, there isn't any horde presence there. The amount of tin ore spawns in hillsbrad means that if you want lots of tin ore, you go to hillsbrad.

Comment: I wasn't thinking so much of PvP, as how far you have to travel to get back to a mailbox and vendors to clear out your bags.

Comment: There's always the little base in Arathi Highlands, not that far away. Or you could get bigger bags! There might even be a mailbox at Chillwind Camp in Western Plaguelands, which is even closer